# Can I implement message security in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, x509certificate2

I have a requirement to use Web API, and implement security on those calls.  I know how to do what I need in WCF, but Web API is frustrating in its efforts to be simpler.  SSL, I think I got that.  I have a cert installed on the server, that I somehow need to also install on the client, and I set that by adding the cert to the `WebRequestHandler.ClientCertificates` property...  I think that's how it works.

But I also wanted to implement message security where I sign and encrypt the message with a personal certificate installed on the client and the client only.  This certificate could then be used to verify the identity of the client, and process the message.

My question is, then, threefold

1. Do I understand the SSL part of this correctly?
2. Can I implement a second certificate to sign the message, or does this functionality not exist in Web API?
3. If not possible to use the certificate, what about an X509SecurityToken?  I can't find any examples of this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'implement security' ? SSL protects the transport, but would not give you message level encryption of the content. You might inquire if using a protected transport (HTTPS) satisfies the security requirement. If not, then as Dominick indicated you would have to implement your own client-server encryption of the payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP itself does not have a specification to do message security. You could roll your own, but you are on your own here.

I think you got the SSL part wrong - the server cert does not need to be installed on the client. You simply need to use a cert that is trusted by the client (e.g. the issuer is trusted).

*In addition* you can use a client certificate to authenticate the client.

Comment: I've been trying with just a certificate installed on the client.  I can post the code, I get errors.

Comment: Check out how SSL works. For the server authentication + transport protection part you need no code at all.